# How can I print how many bytes has been read to console with Assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

Here is my code (**buffer.asm**)

```
section .bss
    bufflen equ 2
    buff: resb bufflen

    whatreadlen equ 1
    whatread: resb whatreadlen

section .data

section .text

global main

main:
    nop
    read:
        mov eax,3           ; Specify sys_read
        mov ebx,0           ; Specify standard input
        mov ecx,buff        ; Where to read to...
        mov edx,bufflen     ; How long to read
        int 80h             ; Tell linux to do its magic
        mov esi,eax         ; copy sys_read return value to esi
        mov [whatread],eax  ; Store how many byte reads info to memory at loc whatread

        mov eax,4           ; Specify sys_write
        mov ebx,1           ; Specify standart output
        mov ecx,[whatread]  ; Get the value at loc whatread to ecx
        add ecx,0x30        ; convert digit in EAX to corresponding character digit
        mov edx,1           ; number of bytes to be written
        int 80h             ; Tell linux to do its work
```

When I call this like:

```
./buffer > output.txt < all.txt
```

(Assume all.txt has some text in it like "abcdef")

I am expecting to see a number in the console. However I see nothing. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Please note that you are storing a dword EAX at a location that was setup to recieve a byte using `resb whatreadlen`!

Comment: @user3144770 ah yes.. you are right. thanks. but shouldn't it automatically save a byte long from eax in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a value to sys_write instead of an address, that's not going to work.

Write this instead :

```
main:
    nop
    read:
        mov eax,3           ; Specify sys_read
        mov ebx,0           ; Specify standard input
        mov ecx,buff        ; Where to read to...
        mov edx,bufflen     ; How long to read
        int 80h             ; Tell linux to do its magic
        mov esi,eax         ; copy sys_read return value to esi
        add eax, 30h        ;; Convert number to ASCII digit
        mov [whatread],eax  ; Store how many byte reads info to memory at loc whatread

        mov eax,4           ; Specify sys_write
        mov ebx,1           ; Specify standart output
        lea ecx,[whatread]  ;; Get the address of whatread in ecx
        mov edx,1           ; number of bytes to be written
        int 80h             ; Tell linux to do its work
```

Here we're converting our (hopefully single digit) return value from sys_read into an ASCII digit, storing it at `whatread`, then telling sys_write to write from `whatread` as if it was a pointer to a string of 1 character (which it is).

And test it with `echo aaa | ./buffer > output.txt`

Comment: Now I am getting: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @KorayTugay Then that's probably a problem with the rest of your code, I just tested this snippet :). Add a `mov eax, 1; mov ebx, 0; int 80h` just after this code to sys_exit(0) and see if it works.

Comment: thanks you are right it works @tux3 but can I do it without lea and using move instead?

Comment: I have a text file with text in it: "kor" ("" excluded in the file) When I run this code I get the number 4, why? (bufflen equ 1024 btw)

Comment: @KorayTugay that's because there's (almost) always a newline ('\n') character at the end of files. You're reading 3 characters plus the newline, that's 4. You can do `echo -n kor > file.txt` if you don't want the newline.

Comment: You are right again, hex editor shows:6B 6F 72 61 0A however my text file does not have a line feed. I did not press enter before saving it. only "kor" Also what is 61, strange..

Comment: @KorayTugay The newline is added automatically, all programs add one at the end even if you don't do it.

Comment: Sorry, 61 is for "a" I was looking at a file with "kora" instead of "kor". Sorry...